# How to locate a particular place in macOS?

Tags: macos, command-line, path

In this [link](http://audioplastic.org/blog/2013/01/23/matlab-cobalt/), there is the unix command

```
$HOME/.matlab/<version>/matlab.prf.
```

How to go to this place by using terminal?

Answer (score 4):

`$HOME` is your home directory.  This is the directory you are in when you start a terminal window.  Normal using on Mac (and most unix-like systems, is that your home directory has the same name as your short user name.  So if you are Mike Smith, and have a short user name of msmith then the value of `$HOME` is (usually) `/Volumes/Users/msmith`.

`HOME` is an ***environment variable***. If I create a script or a set of directions and use `$HOME` instead of `/Volumes/Users/msmith`, then that script can be used by other people.  When I log in, during the startup process MY `HOME` variable is set to `/Volumes/Users/sherwood`.

The < > notation means, "Don't type this literally, but find out what the value is, and use that instead.  No automatic substitution this time.

In general on Mac and UNIX/Linux/*BSD systems a file in your home directory (possibly other places) that starts with a period contains settings for that software package.  So `.matlab` is a directory of Matlab settings, startup scripts, this and that.

`<version>` is replaced by the version number of your Matlab installation.  You may have several different Matlab versions.

The easiest way to find this is by typing

```
ls .matlab
```

In your home directory.  I don't have Matlab on my Mac, so I'm only guessing, but you will probably see something like `R2009b` and/or `R2011a`.

So if your username was `msmith`, you could refer to this file as

```
~/.matlab/R2011a/matlab.prf
```

The `~` is another shorthand meaning the 'home directory of'. Often you can just use `~` by itself.  As `~/.matlab`.  `~/.matlab` and `$HOME/.matlab` are two ways of saying the same thing.

If you need to GO there -- to see what else is in that directory, just chop off everything after the last `/` and put `cd` in front.

Thus

```
cd ~/.matlab/R2011a/
```

will leave you in the folder containing `matlab.prf`

---

The default settings folder in newer MatLAB versions seems to be `$HOME/Library/Application Support/MathWorks/MATLAB/version/` though:

the path to `matlab.prf` is then e.g.

```
"$HOME/Library/Application Support/MathWorks/MATLAB/R2016b/matlab.prf"
```

Comment: See if it's clearer now.

Comment: Yep - also mentioning $HOME being an env var is appreciated ;-). I already thought of editing it into your answer myself, but then I hesitated. I will add a proper MatLAB like version number later - I think it looks like this: *RYearRevision* +1

Comment: You said "_$HOME is an environment variable._" and `$HOME` **is not** a _variable_, `HOME` is the _variable_. In Terminal, if you execute `unset $HOME` it errors with `-bash: unset: /Users/name': not a valid identifier` because `$HOME` **is not** the _variable_, it' expands the _variable_. However `unset HOME` works without error. See `Shell Variables` in the BASH manual page.

Comment: Good point @user3439894.  Fixed.